# Why won't certain videos preview in MacOS Finder any more?

Tags: file-formats, mac, prores, preview

It used to be possible to preview all ProRes and PNG sequence .mov video files in the Finder in MacOS, by selecting the file and pressing the spacebar.
Now it isn't. It's a pain. Is there a workaround? Please don't say open them in an app.

Comment: which prores codec are you using? 422? 4444xq?

Comment: When I look at it in Finder info it says PNG sequence (it's a .mov), when I open it in Quicktime it says it needs to convert it, and then opens as ProRes 4444

Comment: I swear I used to be able to preview these in Finder. Suspect it was before Quicktime 32 bit went away....

Comment: That is very strange indeed. I've only had this issue when converting files with ffmpeg to prores. What's the program you're putting the files out with?

Comment: I'm not exporting the files - they're clips from here: https://www.videocopilot.net/products/action2/

Comment: (can't upload them due to copyright)

Comment: Huh, interesting. I suspect that the files are encoded in a way that is unsupported now. However, I've had this experience too, and opening the file with quicktime and letting it "convert" (whatever that means) and then saving that file does the trick. If you've bought like 500 files, it would be tedious to do that for all files, though.